# Background functionality of a mobile phone

Tags: communication, system, system-on-chip

I'm asking this question out of curiosity. In general, we have around 6 to 7 radios in a smartphone. the modulation schemes, estimation procedures, synchronization methods are different for each radio. How do the people who develop a smartphone, fit all these radios on to a single chip?

And also I've studied that ARM processor will be used for basic call initiation, call forwarding and call receiving.

So is there an ARM processor that is present along with the SOC, or everything is fit into the a single SOC.? Or they use an FPGA to fit all the radios.?

Thanks in advance
phani tej

Comment: What makes you think that they are all in one chip? If not anything else, for EMC compatibility that wouldn't be a great idea.

Comment: @clabacchio most cell phones use multifunction radio chips. Broadcom produces a 11b/g/n/a/btle/fm/lte single chip solution that's all the rage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at a teardown of e.g. the iPhone: https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+4S+Teardown/6610 . Especially step 9 of that page. There's the ARM processor, the A5, which counts as the "main" SoC. Next to it is the radio processor, Qualcomm RTR8605, which Chipworks have a teardown of: http://www.chipworks.com/en/technical-competitive-analysis/resources/blog/iphone-4s-teardown-a-closer-look-at-the-chips-inside/?lang=en&Itemid=815

The die shot makes it clear what's going on. You can see several blocks with distinct boundaries, and a number of inductors (the octagonal ring structures). Each of those is for a different radio function.

[image]

No mass-market product would use FPGAs, it's too expensive.

Comment: Great answer. Id just add that it can be a combination as well. Apple prefers complete inhouse design of the main processor, but some other phones have a single chip main processor + radios. Broadcom produces many SOCs like that.